# limit number of line the user can draw and erasuring it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code that allow the user to draw lines.
The problem is I don't know how to limit the number of lines the user can create to one, and how to delete it so that the user can try again.

```
public GameObject linePrefab;
public GameObject currentLine;

public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
public EdgeCollider2D edgeCollider;
public List<Vector2> fingerPositions;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        CreateLine();
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector2 tempFingerPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Vector2.Distance(tempFingerPos, fingerPositions[fingerPositions.Count - 1]) > .1f)
        {
            UpdateLine(tempFingerPos);
        }
    }
}

void CreateLine()
{
    currentLine = Instantiate(linePrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    lineRenderer = currentLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    edgeCollider = currentLine.GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
    fingerPositions.Clear();
    fingerPositions.Add(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
    fingerPositions.Add(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, fingerPositions[0]);
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, fingerPositions[1]);
    edgeCollider.points = fingerPositions.ToArray();
}

void UpdateLine(Vector2 newFingerPos)
{
    fingerPositions.Add(newFingerPos);
    lineRenderer.positionCount++;
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(lineRenderer.positionCount - 1, newFingerPos);
    edgeCollider.points = fingerPositions.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this code:

```
void Update()
{
//--- some code here.
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if(CanDrawLine)  //Checking if allowed to create line
           CreateLine();
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if(CanDrawLine)  //Checking if allowed to create line
        {
            Vector2 tempFingerPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Vector2.Distance(tempFingerPos, fingerPositions[fingerPositions.Count - 1]) > .1f)
            {
                UpdateLine(tempFingerPos);
            }
        }
    }
//--- some code here
}

[SerializeField]
int m_maxCountToCreate = 10;
int m_numberOfLinesCreated = 0;

bool CanDrawLine
{
   get { return m_numberOfLinesCreated == m_maxCountToCreate; }
}


void CreateLine()
{
    m_numberOfLinesCreated++;
    // your code here.
}
```

Comment: i tried but it doesnt seem to work. also what is:
[SerializeField]

Comment: @liel7200, Can you explain, what exactly is wrong with the code?

Comment: For **[SerializeField]**: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html

Comment: it seems now that when i try to limit the number line it always create an extra one i tried to same varisins but it didnt work